# Nginx service not starting

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

Am trying to setup Minikube, and have a challenge. My minikube is setup, and I started the Nginex pod. I can see that the pod is up, but the service doesn't appear as active. On dashboard too, although the pod appears the depolyment doesn't show up. Here are my power shell command outputs.

Am learning this technology and may have missed something. My understanding is that when using docker tools, no explicit configurations are necessary at docker level, other than setting it up. Am I wrong here ? If so where ?

[relevant PS output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTpkF.jpg)

Comment: Please put the output in a code block, not as an image.

Comment: Please add relevant info like deployment and service definitions to the question in code blocks and not images. Most likely you didn't create the service.

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#expose

Answer (score 1):

Lets deploy hello-nginx deployment

```
C:\> kubectl.exe run hello-nginx --image=nginx --port=80
deployment "hello-nginx" created
```

View List of pods

```
c:\> kubectl.exe get pods
NAME                           READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
hello-nginx-6d66656896-hqz9j   1/1       Running   0          6m
```

Expose as a Service

```
c:\> kubectl.exe expose deployment hello-nginx --type=NodePort
service "hello-nginx" exposed
```

List exposed services using minikube

```
c:\> minikube.exe service list
|-------------|----------------------|-----------------------------|
|  NAMESPACE  |         NAME         |             URL             |
|-------------|----------------------|-----------------------------|
| default     | hello-nginx          | http://192.168.99.100:31313 |
| default     | kubernetes           | No node port                |
| kube-system | kube-dns             | No node port                |
| kube-system | kubernetes-dashboard | http://192.168.99.100:30000 |
|-------------|----------------------|-----------------------------|
```

Access Nginx from browser http://192.168.99.100:31313

Answer (score -2):

This method can be used
this worked for me on centos 7

```
$ systemctl enable nginx 

$ systemctl restart nginx
```

or

```
$ systemctl start nginx
```

Comment: The question here is about docker managed nginx service not the one managed by systemd. So this answer isn’t relevant.